# Adding a Native .dll file from SIMULINK to Visual Studios C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have created a .dll file using SIMULINK's embedded coder. (System target file is set to : ert_shrlib.tlc) It successfully builds into Model_win64.dll. Now I want to reference it from Visual studios.

I first tried using the "add reference" tool but got the following error: **A reference to 'file path\Model_win64.dll'**

I then searched around for a solution online and am getting that this error is cause by the .dll file being a native .dll so I should use the DllImportAttribute Class  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx

So the code I have currently is

```
﻿using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace GUI_Interface
{
    class Main
    {
    [DllImport("Modbot_Model_win64.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int[] MPC(double x, double y, double theta, double Vx, double Vy, double Vtheta);

    public static BackgroundWorker test()
    {
        ints = MPC(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

And I get the runtime error:Cannot marshal 'return value': **Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.** I've tried reading up on managed/unmanaged types but I just can't wrap my head around it in order to solve this issue. Any proposed solutions or info on managed/unmanaged would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try changing your exe so that it is x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly use int[] as return type. It's managed but the dll returned is not.

Change return type to "IntPtr" to receive a pointer.

```
[DllImport("Modbot_Model_win64.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr MPC(double x, double y, double theta, double Vx, double Vy, double Vtheta);
```

Then use Marshall copy to get the data

```
IntPtr ints = MPC(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int ret[] = new int[N]; //N is the number of elements
Marshall.Copy(ints, ret, 0, N);
```

Comment: Ethan is right, you need to use IntPtr to correctly handle the unmanaged response as the type is not necessarily a CLR supported type. IntPtr will also correctly handle 64 vs 32 bit differences. Also, why not use MatLab's COM library instead? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html